# What happen for knowledge in the past tense

Tags: verbs, tenses, semantics

For an action in the past tense, it means the action stops at the current time. For example, "I lived in that house" means that I lived in the house sometime in the past and do not live in the house now.

I want to know if this holds for stative verbs like *know*. In other words, does "I knew him" means I came to know him sometime in the past, and I forget him now or have not seen or heard of him for a long time?

Comment: It's not black and white, but it does not mean I forget him. It could mean I knew him then to be honest, but recently I had bad experiences with him.

Comment: To add what @YosefBaskin said, if you no longer associate with him, you would probably say it like this, "I used to know him".

Comment: “I knew him” can also be used when the person has died.

Comment: "I lived in that house in 2001" does not mean that I no longer live there.  "I knew him in 2001" does not mean that I no longer know him.

Comment: "I lived in that house in 2001" does mean that I no longer live there. If I still live there, it would be ""I have lived in that house since 2001".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its most likely meaning, *I knew John Smith* would imply that John Smith is now dead; see the numerous examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1600&bih=778&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNRsQsfTnMY4rt65K0TGHoWt5ANNUw%3A1576539549028&ei=nRX4XaegAeKyggfGnafYAg&q=%22I+knew+him%22&oq=%22I+knew+him%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...173511.173876.0.174430.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.LOZFlnIiurk).

As Jim said in the comments, if you want to avoid that implication, use *I used to know John Smith.*

You can also avoid that implication in other ways, e.g. by saying *When I was in college, I knew a man called John Smith* (see e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=DteaBgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA28&dq=%22I%20knew%20a%20man%20called%22&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q=%22I%20knew%20a%20man%20called%22&f=false)). This makes no implication that John Smith is now dead, and it doesn't imply you've forgotten him. It does imply that you haven't had any information about him in a long while.